# Numbering all lines of an array

Tags: equations, numbering, arrays

I know there are already many topics about that but I couldn't find an appropriate answer (most of the time the given solutions are not adapted to my case). Here is my code (some command have been renamed) :

```
\begin{subequations}
\begin{array}{rcll}
\dint_{K} \underline{E}_h \cdot \underline{z} dx + \dint_{K}\Phi_h \nabla\cdot \underline{z} dx -\dint_{\partial K} \lambda_h \underline{z} \cdot \underline{n} d\sigma & = & 0, & \forall\  \underline{z}_h \in\mathbb{Q}^k(K), \\[4mm]
\dint_K \nabla \cdot \underline{E}_h p dx & = & \dint_K (1-\rho)p dx, & \forall\  p \in \mathbb{P}^k(K), \\[4mm]
\dint_e \ldbrack \underline{E}_h \rdbrack \mu d\sigma & = & 0, & \forall\ \mu\in\mathbb{P}^k(e).
\end{array}
\label{eq:Poisson-RT
\end{subequations}
```

I would like to keep the vertical alignment (all the `\forall` one above the other...) and have a numbering like

```
... (1.a)
... (1.b)
... (1.c)
```

I tryed with `subequation` and `align` but the alignment is not the one expected and `array` is not compatible with `subequation`. `eqnarray` could be acceptable if it did not place characters on top of each other.

Answer (score 2):

You want to use an `align` environment.  Doing something like...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\pagestyle{empty}
\newcommand{\dint}{\int}
\newcommand{\ldbrack}{[}
\newcommand{\rdbrack}{] }
\begin{document}

\begin{subequations}
\begin{align}
\dint_{K} \underline{E}_h \cdot \underline{z} \, dx + \dint_{K}\Phi_h \nabla\cdot \underline{z} \, dx -\dint_{\partial K} \lambda_h \underline{z} \cdot \underline{n} \, d\sigma & = 0,
                && \forall\  \underline{z}_h \in\mathbb{Q}^k(K), \\[4mm]
\dint_K \nabla \cdot \underline{E}_h p \, dx              & = \dint_K (1-\rho)p \, dx,
                && \forall\  p \in \mathbb{P}^k(K),              \\[4mm]
\dint_e \ldbrack \underline{E}_h \rdbrack \mu \, d\sigma  & = 0,
                && \forall\  \mu\in\mathbb{P}^k(e).
\end{align}
\label{eq:Poisson-RT}
\end{subequations}

\end{document}
```

*Please note* I've taken the liberty of redefining some of your commands.  But this should give you the general idea of how to accomplish what you want.

[image]

**edit:** doubled the `&` before `\forall` to align them, and added thin space (`\,`) before all `d<something>` to improve appearance and aid comprehension, as recommended by Knuth (TeXbook, p.168).

Comment: since the original answer was basically the way to go, i made some edits to the code to refine it, and added the resulting image.  didn't seem worth making a second answer, which could just lead to confusion.

Comment: Should we then also write `\mathrm{d}` for the differentials?

Comment: @A.Ellett Using an upright or italic "d" is basically a stylistic decision. The only requirement is consistency (unless norms in some technical field prescribe an upright "d").